# Помогите наложить блок на блок)

Tags: html, css

```
<div class = "parent" width = "1000px">
 <div class = "divOne" width = "700px">
 </div>
 <div class = "divTwo" width = "700px">
 </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос - как сделать что бы первый див был в верхнем левом углу, а второй налазил на первый, и прилипал к нижнему правому углу?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
.divOne {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
}
.divTwo {
    position: relative;
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="divOne">
        <div class="divTwo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

как-то так? задача не совсем точная. Или нужно, чтобы второй див был в самом правом нижнем углу? а не нижнем правом первого?

Comment: спасибо я уже разобрался)))